# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (nodejs tcp server)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a very basic tcp server that can send and receive json data.

See my code:

```
  // Handle incoming messages from clients.
  socket.on('data', function (data) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    if(obj.type == "register") {
        _clientObj[obj.msg] = {
            client: 'Client',
            socketID: socket.name
        }


        console.log("Register...");     

    } else if(obj.type == "message") {


        console.log(socket.name + " --> message: " + obj.msg);  
    }

  });
```

The problem seems to be that sometimes data is not complete and it trows an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

How can i wait before data is finished before i parse out the json?

Answer (score 3):

You could wait for emitting **end** event, and then parse it.

**Example**:

```
// Handle incoming messages from clients.
data = '';
socket.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;
});

// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('end', function () {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);

    if(obj.type == "register") {
        _clientObj[obj.msg] = {
            client: 'Client',
            socketID: socket.name
        }

    console.log("Register...");   

    } else if(obj.type == "message") {
        console.log(socket.name + " --> message: " + obj.msg);  
    }
});
```

**Documentation**: 
http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_event_end_1